# How do I exclude a null element from an ArrayList?

Tags: java

```
//This code for mapping the elements inside xml tag  
public static String getLeukemiaInvolvement(String val) {
    BiMap<String, String> map = HashBiMap.create();
    map.put("01", "6");
    map.put("02", "7");
    map.put("03", "8");
    map.put("04", "9");
    map.put("05", "3");

    return map.inverse().get(val);
}

for (String data : getListStringValForElementTag(element, "organ-involvement1")) {
        if(data != null) {
            sectionAmlAllMds.getOrganInvolvement1().add(Pris3BMdmMapper.getLeukemiaInvolvement(data));
        }

    }
```

How do I ensure my output does not include a null element? I already do the checking for null element but it doesn't work. My output is:

```
 "organInvolvement1": ["01", "04", null, null, "05"]
```

This code will read element array list inside XML tag "organ-involvement1":

```
getListStringValForElementTag(element, "organ-involvement1")
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm guessing `getLeukemiaInvolvement()` can return null for non-null inputs. But please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like in this case, `data` is not null but the value for it is `null`. 
Try this:-

```
if(data != null && Pris3BMdmMapper.getLeukemiaInvolvement(data) != null) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also override the `add` method. But it can be overengineering:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>() {
            @Override
            public boolean add(String e) {
                if (e == null) return false;
                return super.add(e);
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a utility method to exclude nulls from a collection:

```
static void removeNulls(Collection<?> c) {
    while(c.remove(null)) {
        // Do Nothing
   }
}
```

Then, call it whenever you need to remove exclude elements from a collection:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> colors = new ArrayList<>(); 
    Collections.addAll(colors, "red", null, "blue", "green", null);
    removeNulls(colors);
    System.out.println(colors);
}
```